# Last element deformed when using Array Modifer and Bezier Curve

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make tank tracks in Blender 2.8 but whenever I use the bezier curve the last element seems deformed. I tried to close the bezier curve with `F` but still no joy.

[image]

Comment: maybe simply check out how is the curve handle at this position and realign it correctly?

Comment: Thanks! How do I check that? When I go into object mode and check the curve, it seems aligned. (i.e. the lines line up perfectly on the x-plane.

Comment: maybe share your file?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think I figured it out. @moonboots was right that the curve handle was wonky, hence it was pointing the track in a weird directly. My solution was to set the Handle Type in the Edit menu for the curve to "Vector" (Using Shift + V) and I can get straight lines and not have to deal with rotation. Here's the result: